# Plugin Derivatives For Queue and Migration Plugins

Tags: 8, entities, migrations, queue

I've created a custom Content Entity and a custom Content Entity Type, basically I'm mirroring the Node module but the purpose of this is to have external data to be synced with this setup(not using node and the content types because I want the content not to have any canonical pages, and at the same time, I am supposed to have content with landing pages).

[Content Sync](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/third-party-content-synchronization-drupal-migrate) - this link provides a good example of setting up a sync process using the Migrate module. I would need a set of plugins to define the migration process for a custom entity, but since I have multiple types of my custom entity, can it be possible to use derivatives for any types of plugins(Migrate module - source, process, destination and Queue plugins like QueueWorker) to handle each type of custom entity dynamically?

This might be a huge question to dig into, but I'm more interested in a yes/no type of answer, because I can do the investigation myself afterwards, just need to know if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation cannot be derviated, but the class itself yes.